# tool to create mobile version of existing jsp or html pages

Tags: html, jsp, mobile

I have some existing jsp pages and html pages which includes javascript as well. Due to the large number of the pages manual editing is not an option for me. So is there any tool which I can use to atleast help me convert them to some mobile compatible version.

I looked at jquery for mobile too but that doesn't seem to have any convert option for existing files though for generating new files it is awesome.

Any help on this matter will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are your files using CSS? You may be able to build a mobile-friendly version by just adding new rules to the stylesheet, using media queries to target small displays

Comment: actually it was done by another developer who just left the company and all of the pages seem to have hard coded values instead of a few css files and the few of them which exists contain only a small subset of the presentation logic..I already tried editing them but it didnt work the way i wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly doubt there is a tool for this, what would it even do? To make a page specially for mobile platforms is an extremly human task.

What you should do is take a look at your CSS files, which should be general for your whole application, and see what you can do with it. It might not be as good as pages specially designed for small screens, but you should be able to remove the worst problems.

See http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/mobile-css.htm for some examples and help.

Comment: actually as I mentioned before the guy who coded the pages have written messed up code in most of the pages that i require..so the css option is not valid for me.Thanks for the comments though guys

Comment: Something should be doable though, is there not things like a common top menu, sidebars etc? Even if stuff is copy pasted through out all the files, it might be overrideable globally

Comment: there are 205 files in total..so manual editing is out of question..and also the css as i mentioned is not that greatly written ..its missing most of the things that matters ...also the pages were initially not designed for mobile devices so its hard to put them back  into a small screen of 240x320 resolution screens

Comment: What I meant what, let's say you have a `<div id="menu">` declared on most of your pages. You could then include a mobile.css on every page that changes divs with the id "menu". You could also reduce fontsize globally and such. Just including the new css in each file shouldn't take more than 15 minutes.